# Calculating similarity between two lists

Tags: python-3.x, similarity

Is there any way to compute the similarity of two lists considering that the similarity score of shorter lists should be lower than the similarity score of long lists.

For example:

```
listA = [banana]
listB = [banana]
```

`similarity(listA, listB)` should not be 1 but something smaller since the two lists have both length 1.

Comment: Sure, it is possible. For example you could just count the number of elements in common and pass this through any continuous function that has a horizontal asymptote towards +infinity. However, you do not define whether two long list having 3 common elements are supposed to be more similar than two lists of length 2 that are identical. Somewhat the absolute number of common elements and the percent of identical elements are not homogeneous, which leads to infinitely many a-priori equally valid combination choices.

Comment: You need a crisp definition of what you mean by "similarity" to get a quality answer.